# Android Kitkat 4.4 webview in Android 9

Tags: webview, chromium, android-4.4-kitkat, android-9.0-pie, crosswalk

Question: Is it possible to have Android Kitkat version `webview (chromium)` on Android 9?

Problem: I have some webpages and I want to show them in `webview` but the webpages are developed using old technologies like `appCache` and `application Manifest`.
The webpages are hosted on a hardware based custom control system which has low specs and the server on the control system does not support `https` so we cannot move to technologies like `service workers`.

These webpages works properly on tablet having android 4.4 kitkat. So that's why I am asking about any possibility of integrating `kitkat webview (chromium)` in Android 9

I tried to use `crosswalk webview`, it worked but when compiled through old `sdk version 23` but `crosswalk` not compiles on latest android `sdk's like 29 and 30`

Answer (score 1):

No,it's not possible but you can do one thing that instead of serving a webpage via http or https in your app you can serve a local file to that webview.To do so :-

Method 1

1. create assets folder.
2. create your files in that folder like index.html,style.css .
3. set Webview url to "file:///android_asset/index.html"
4. It's done.

Method 2

1. Use Cordova to do so.